# Laravel Mix Javascript undefined function onClick

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am using Laravels Mix feature with javascript and I am having a bit of trouble. I've made a new javascript file and included it in app.js, I've then done a function in this file. I want to call it from an onClick event however its giving me an error.

In cart.js I have an array that is adding all the products, and I also have this line of coded added.

```
<a onClick="removeProduct(${product["id"]})" class="btn-remove1">Remove</a>
```

Also in cart.js I have this function, that needs to be called on the onClick event.

```
function removeProduct(id) {
    console.log(id);
}
```

However, It then gives me this error when trying to call removeProduct()

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: removeProduct is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

So I'm not sure how to handle this, I guess I could use jQuery and wait for the object to be clicked and then get the id but just wondering if I can do it by onClick. Thanks for any help!

Edit:

Looking into this some more, Webpack is including Cart.js and in app.jss the function removeProduct() is there. Do I need to somehow call it like Cart.removeProduct() or something? (I've never used web pack/mix before)

Comment: It says `removeProduct` isn't defined. There's no code in the question that would define it. Why do you think it should be defined? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I guess I could use jQuery and wait for the object to be clicked and then get the id" — How would that help? There's nothing that suggests there is a problem with the ID.

Comment: @Quentin I've added that function that's in included in app.js and included in the html

Comment: The error message says it isn't defined. So either there is an error elsewhere in app.js or app.js isn't being loaded.

Comment: @Quentin The thing is, it is being included and it is being loaded as I have other code. I've edited my post to explain a bit more. I'm appending with jQuery to add the onClick to the html in the same file and its added fine to the HTML file, This is why I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out with webpack you need to define it in the global scope. You can simply do that by adding this line of code.

```
window.removeProduct = removeProduct;
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cache and then check or check that js file is included into your file or not.